# can we have multiple branch with one database on magento2 cloud?

Tags: magento-2.1, database, magento2-cloud

on Magento cloud when we create a new branch we have to have new database and instance but it is not efficient, we should be able to have different branches using same database, is it possible? I know that we can have them on local and merge to our branch but this is not acceptable I mean I want to take test a branch on cloud why should I setup environment and database again and again?

can we push the changes on cloud branch without rebuilding again when we change the composer? it is taking us 10 minuets for every deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During development, you can use own external DB.
The **.magento.env.yaml.dist** file contains an example of how to configure DB connections. Just find the description of **DATABASE_CONFIGURATION**

Unfortunately, each push triggers rebuilding and redeploy.
To decrease deploy time during development you can enable the generation of static on-demand. Just find the description of **SCD_ON_DEMAND** in the **.magento.env.yaml.dist** file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.